# How to automatically power off device after a period of inactivity?

Tags: automation, power-on

I want my phone to power off after being idle for some time (say, 15 minutes). This is a common feature in computers, but I couldn't find it on my Android settings, nor an app to help me out.

I don't want a scheduled shutdown, but a shutdown after inactivity.

Is that possible?

Comment: Android is designed for a smartphone which means it should by default stay awake all the time, thus they don't have power saving modes like suspend to RAM. Some manufacturers add time based power on/off functions.

Answer (score 1):

you need an automation app like [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) or [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm).

1. Set a trigger that is related to inactivity, like screen off or no movement detected by the sensors
2. Add timeout before executing the power off command
3. The power off command

If your phone is rooted, it is a very easy thing to do. If your phone is not rooted you can use [Shizuku](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=moe.shizuku.privileged.api).

Answer (score 1):

Following [theggputest55's response](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/250878/44325),

Using MacroDroid:

1. Set trigger: screen off
2. Set an action: wait before next action, set to 20 minutes
3. Set an action: if clause, if screen off, i.e. Is the screen still off after 20 minutes?
4. Set an action: reboot/power off (power off)

Comment: That answer has alreay been given.

Comment: I couldn't find Set trigger:screen off.
I couldn't find wait before next action.
I don't know how to use if clause, if screen off, i.e...
I couldn't find action reboot/power off (power off).
Please describe it completely. I'm not professional.
Thanks anyway. .